# Laravel artisan: Redis down - config:cache fails with ConnectionException

Tags: laravel, caching, configuration, laravel-artisan

I had a remote Redis cache which went down. I tried changing the config via .env and then running `php artisan config:cache` on the server to use a different server. However this didn't work and resulted in a `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException`. My question is: why is it trying to connect to redis to update/cache the config? How can I prevent this in the future? Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Found [this thread](https://laravel.io/forum/11-10-2016-how-to-catch-predisconnectionconnectionexception) from 6 years ago with the same issue. But, unfortunately, no solution.

Comment: You define your caching storage in your `.env`, so if you don't want it to use Redis for now, change it to something else. Check `config/cache.php` to see your other options, but `file` may work for now.

Comment: That said, I don't know if there's a way to have a "backup cache" option for when your Redis server fails.

Comment: I did change the relevant settings in .env. The problem was that the new config couldn't be read because it was previously cached. Running `artisan config:cache` or `artisan config:clear` resulted in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling the cache in your application config? Otherwise, as long as the cache is down, you'll see a connection exception as you have configured Laravel to do that (to throw the exception).

You also need to clear *all* existing caches as Laravel persists the configuration so that the running application may not recognize the new settings as the old settings are in use until everything is reloaded.

This is easy to miss as all the wording suggests configuration would be injected late through the environment. But it's not, this happens pretty early which requires you to "reboot" the application:

1. Shutdown the application server Laravel runs under
2. Shutdown the process manager Laravel runs under (if any)
3. Remove all temporary files (or redeploy the pristine copy from the artifact)
4. Configure the application from the clean state it is in.
5. And start the application server again under which you run the Laravel app.

The reason why this is so, is that this could be many (depends not only on the application configuration but also the servers and managers) therefore this list may appear longer as it needs to be for your specific configuration, but as you're having troubles to find the culprit, I think it's good to share the whole procedure.

The short answer should be: Redeploy your existing application revision with the changed configuration. Fix all gaps in your deployment process (e.g. stale caches) when you find them. This will become more fluent with each deployment.

Comment: This is ultimately how it was resolved by changing the config and redeploying the app which restarts nginx and clears the config etc. I just thought it doesn't make sense for redis to throw an exception when you're trying to cache your config settings.

Comment: Yes, that obviously may not appear _necessary_ (the throwing), the cache could just fall-through, however on the other side you'd like to know if the configuration is broken. Now you can't have both things at once and throwing the exception is normally more fail-safe as otherwise it is easy to miss a configuration error as most of these processes are intended to run unattended. [_"Fail-fast systems are usually designed to stop normal operation rather than attempt to continue a possibly flawed process."_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).

Comment: But that is not the case here. I'm actively changing the config from a "broken" state to a fixed state, but the system fails to update to the new config.

Comment: @tone7: Could it be that `artisan optimize:clear` does not throw? Sorry if this is stating the obvious because I'm not entirely sure for every setup, on my project it says it is clearing the cached bootstrap files firsthand. There still might be a leaking abstraction thought, but from how I understand it, afterwards the application should be bootstrapped again and take any config changes.